# Swift safe unwrapping optional a Class Constant without redundancy

Tags: ios, swift, variables, unwrap, swift-optionals

I am trying to get more Structure into my code so I am implementing this `UserDefaultsService`:

```
class UserDefaultsService {
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)

    static let shared = UserDefaultsService()
    
    func updateDataSourceArrayWithWishlist(wishlist: Wishlist) {
        guard var dataSourceArray = defaults?.getDataSourceArray() else { return }
        if let index = dataSourceArray.firstIndex(where: ({$0.id == wishlist.id})) {
            dataSourceArray[index] = wishlist
            defaults?.setDataSourceArray(data: dataSourceArray)
        }
    }
    
    func getDataSourceArray() -> [Wishlist]? {
        return defaults?.getDataSourceArray()
    }
}
```

But as you can see `defaults` is optional. I know I could safe unwrap it with `guard` for example everytime I am using it but isn' there some better/cleaner way to do this? What I am thinking is to only unwrap it once and then I can use it everywhere in `UserDefaultsService`.

Comment: You can force unwrap (`!`), but typically what I like to do is to use `guard` to conditionally unwrap or fail with `preconditionFailure`

Comment: @NewDev that is what I want to to but I can not use `guard` in a class variable

Comment: you can use a computed property. Or, you can use an immediately executed closure, i.e. `let default = { guard let ... }()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!` end of it's declaration

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)!
```

Comment: But that could crash

Comment: ? but if `UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)` is nil? And I force unwrap it ? why cant it crash?

Comment: the above line will create the suite defaults if not exists and link to it if exists no crashes here only make sure you have a group with the used name so your data is accessed in extensions

Comment: huh, I did not know that.. why is it optional then? Anyway, you answered it. Thanks

Comment: try it yourself and it won't crash with any constant

Comment: I believe you :D its just not the expected behavior imo